# Delete a user and all associated data

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to delete a user and with that delete the following, user, and food data.  Right now the Auth user delete only deletes the sign in data.  I am stuck on how to delete the data for the following.
I am searching the collection for any fields that contain the "following" userUID.  But am having issues deleting the results.

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("relationships").whereField("followedUID", isEqualTo: currentLoggedInUserUID).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
    } else {
        for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
            print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")

            document.delete()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a screenshot of the data you're trying to delete? It's hard to figure out what all the names point to without seeing that.

Answer (score 0):

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("relationships").whereField("followedUID", isEqualTo: currentLoggedInUserUID).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
                            if let err = err {
                                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                            } else {
                                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                                    print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")

                                    Firestore.firestore().collection("relationships").document(document.documentID).delete()
                                }
                            }
                    }
```

I was able to get this to work with this line:

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("relationships").document(document.documentID).delete()
```

The document.documentID was the key.